# OpenCV detect and compute image features

Tags: opencv, image-processing, panoramas, image-stitching

Recently upgraded OpenCV from 3.4.5. to OpenCV 4.2.0.

Before I followed this stitching example: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5131619a1a4d1d3a860b5da431742cc6be945332/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp (particularly line 480). After upgrading, I altered the code to align more with this newer example: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp (Note line 481).

Problem is with this new `computeImageFeatures` function, I am getting less detected features. Older code with same images gave me 1400+ features but `computeImageFeatures` gave me exactly 500 features per image. Any ideas how to "fix" this? I believe it also causes the "Bundle Adjuster" to fail later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation of [`cv::ORB::create`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/db/d95/classcv_1_1ORB.html#adc371099dc902a9674bd98936e79739c), default value of `nfeatures` argument is `500`:

The first argument is `nfeatures`, you may set the first argument to grater number like `2000`.

Here are the constructor arguments:

```C++
static Ptr<ORB> cv::ORB::create (int     nfeatures = 500,
                                 float   scaleFactor = 1.2f,
                                 int     nlevels = 8,
                                 int     edgeThreshold = 31,
                                 int     firstLevel = 0,
                                 int     WTA_K = 2,
                                 int     scoreType = ORB::HARRIS_SCORE,
                                 int     patchSize = 31,
                                 int     fastThreshold = 20 
                                )
```

Try modifying:

```C++
if (features_type == "orb")
{
    finder = ORB::create();
}
```

to

```C++
if (features_type == "orb")
{
    finder = ORB::create(2000);
}
```

In case you are not using ORB, but other type of features, read the documentation of the constructor.
I assume all types has a limiter argument.

Comment: wow thanks I did not know that! I knew it was kind of suspicious that the amount of features was exactly 500